# How do I loop something and wait for something before re-looping? [swift]

Tags: swift

Im basically trying to make a segment of code run over and over once they tap once, and run only if the previous run was completed.

How would I do this exactly, Im completely new to Swift.

Comment: What does re-looping mean? Are you referring to each iteration or the whole loop to start again?

Comment: re-looping as in the whole loop starting again

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your first loop, put a variable that sets to true and then under the IBAction where they tap once, check if that variable is true or not and if it is true, do your re-loop.

Another way you could do it is loop in the viewDidLoad, which is called before any visuals appear. This way, there's no way they could tap the button or whatever you're monitoring until the view has appeared, which is a separate function.

But I doubt you need to wait for a loop to finish, because the execution time of a loop is so fast it will have happened before they can tap (unless it's a very long loop).

Comment: but Im trying to make these sprites go from the top to bottom of the screen in a random position.

Comment: So far I made it so when you tap, the sprites go down and follow some calculations to go randomly downward, but now I want it so this keeps repeating without the player having to tap to repeat it. I was gonna make it wait for the sprites to reach the bottom then repeat the loop again, and keep doing this until a certain condition is met.

Comment: @KarimA.Karim so you want sprites to move in random directions for a specified amount of time?

Comment: Yes, basically, I have 2 asteroid sprites and they move down from the top to bottom of the screen, but take a random amount of time and are all random sizes, So far I made it so whenever you tap the asteroids start their decent, but Im re-using the same sprite, so if they tap mid-way in the decent, the sprites that were descending go back up.

Answer (score -1):

1) IBAction ( code would  start to run)
2) You could use a if statement to check to see if what you want done is done.
3) You could use a for to determine how long the code is ran.